# Array.map index is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in my React:

```
{
    comments.map((comment, index) =>
        console.log({index}), 
        <Textfield key = {index} placeholder = "Add Comment" Id = "addComment" / >
    )
}
```

However, this returns me error that `'index' is not defined  no-undef` on the console.log line. This is the state:

```
const [comments,setComments] = useState([[]])
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: When function has more than one line in it, you should use curly braces.
and you can directly log index without { } and then return <TextField>

Comment: change **useState** to: ([])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return an an element from map function. Here you just try what exactly? I think you just need to wrap your function with `{ }` and use `return` statement.

```
{
    comments.map((comment, index) => {
        console.log({index});
        return <Textfield key = {index} placeholder ="Add Comment" Id="addComment" />;
    })
}
```

Comment: Your return statement should be on one line with the `<Textfield .../>` or surrunded by `()` otherwise the `map` function always returns undefined/null.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are just missing some curly braces around your map function

```
{
    comments.map((comment, index) => {
        console.log(index);
        return <Textfield key={index} placeholder="Add Comment" Id="addComment" />;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add { } in your array function

```
{
    comments.map((comment, index) => {
        console.log(index), 
        return <Textfield key = {index} placeholder = "Add Comment" Id = "addComment" / >
    )}
}
```